# NTFS recovery after installing ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, ntfs, vmfs

I got this server where I had a Windows 2003 installation on, and I didn't think I needed it anymore, so I desided to install ESXi on it for testing purpose.
But now I just found out that there where some important files on the disk !!

Anyone know if it is possible to recover those data, if so, how ??

Comment: Presumably you've never backed it up?

Answer (score 4):

You're probably very, very screwed.  If the data is really valuable, a forensic data recovery place can probably get most of it back, but it'll be incredibly expensive.

This is why we always quarantine drives for (at least) 3 months between decommissioning the hardware and reusing the disks.  Having a bunch of spare disks on hand is orders of magnitude cheaper than the serious-looking men with electron microscopes.

Comment: I was afraid that it would be the answer I would get, but I had to ask :)